# As seen in movies, is it medically sound to treat a bruise with raw meat?

Tags: medical-science, alternative-medicine

I've seen in numerous movies that after a person gets beaten up in a fight they place a chunk of raw meat on their face. I found [this link](http://goaskalice.columbia.edu/black-eye-cure) making reference to the practice and [this one](http://wowforbruises.com/random-myths-about-treating-bruises/) claiming it's a myth (though I have no regards for the validity of the website). My questions are:

1. Was there ever a time when applying raw meat to some sort of external injury was common?
2. What type of meat was used?
3. According to current medical research is it safe to use this treatment?

Answer (score 24):

The answer to your question title is **no**.

The act of putting raw meat on a bruise comes from Hollywood and cartoons, and it usually is adopted when you have a **black eye**, rather than just any bruise. But what works is the cold factor of the frozen meat and not the meat itself, since cold naturally constrains blood vessels and helps reducing the swelling.

In fact, using meat could even be dangerous because you might cause an infection.

This is always strongly discouraged, for example on the page for [First Aid](http://firstaid.about.com/od/softtissueinjuries/ht/07_black_eye.htm) on About.com:

> Never put raw meat on a black eye. There is a [first aid myth](http://firstaid.about.com/od/firstaidbasics/tp/06_bad1staid.htm) that putting steak on a black eye will help it heal faster. It will not. In fact, putting raw meat on a black eye is more likely to cause an infection (see [E coli](http://firstaid.about.com/od/infections/qt/06_Ecoli.htm)).

And also on [Geteyesmart](http://www.geteyesmart.org/eyesmart/diseases/black-eye-treatment.cfm)<sup>1</sup>:

> [...] Despite what you see in movies or on television, you should never put a raw steak or other raw meat on a black eye. The bacteria on raw meat poses a high risk of infection, and this method of treating a black eye has no scientific basis.

A frozen bag of veggies would likely be cleaner than raw meat, but an even better solution would be using ice packs for medical use or cold compresses.

---

<sup>1: American Academy of Ophthalmology Launches Expanded GetEyeSmart.org, a Trusted Source for Eye Health Information. [Source](http://www.aao.org/newsroom/release/20110210.cfm)</sup>

Comment: Where does the myth come from, though? I think this predates Hollywood.

Comment: @KonradRudolph My impression is that, in times where there were less resources, home remedies were the usual approach to problems. And if you think about it a lot of the people that are old now used to do/see it as kids, so that reflected on the cartoon/Hollywood creations. Should I try to research this and back it up in my answer?

Comment: *Even if just eating is mentioned here, the risk of infection is also likely to occur in circumstances like applying it on wounds or a black eye.* - I think this needs a reference

Comment: @Chad Aren't the already available sources enough? They refer to the same thing basically.

Comment: @Alenanno - If you want to delete that sentence then sure... if you want to keep that claim in there you need a source.  Actually you probably need a source for the claim that the peas(or veggies) are likely cleaner than the raw meat to...

Comment: Nice reply. Why do you put a small 1 beside `Geteysmart` which already has a link and then at the body provide a link to the American Academy of Ophthalmology and a different link?

Comment: @Chad Uhmm I'm not sure I agree with you there, but I'll see if I can do something about it.

Comment: @Celeritas The link at the bottom is there to show that the site `Geteyesmart` is reliable enough since the AAO supports it.

Comment: @Alenanno - I agree that site is enough to answer the question.  You could simply remove everything after it and have a valid answer.  Though if you can support those last two claims its a much better and stronger answer

Comment: @Chad I have removed the one about the "eating" part (didn't find anything not ambiguous specifically for it) and fixed the other wording. Now it should work.

Comment: One reason why meat may have been used in movies is that it looks good on screen. An ice pack or a cold compress have a shape that is hard to discern: it's too generic. The meat slab is instantly recognisable and therefore would not puzzle the audience.

Comment: @eje211 But I think the origin is more like "homemade remedies" which then entered the movies. But well... :D

Comment: The use of meat specifically may have more to do with the availability of _something cold_ - refrigerators and cooling chemical reactions are common now, but not so much when this was in larger effect.  If you just have an icebox, you don't really want to remove the ice from it.  If you don't have an icebox, the butcher probably does; raw meat is one of the few things that require such measures for long-term storage.  Fruits/veggies/grains store well in cellars, dairy/eggs are available mostly year-round, etc.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse Yeah, that's probably the origin and no wonder than it then became a sort of common theme.

Comment: Another possible reason for meat (versus something else from the fridge): It is soft and can form comfortably around a wound and not cause any extra pain from pressure. On the other hand, frozen meat is hard while (a bag of) frozen peas is soft. (That was actually my first thought on seeing the question -- after "no, don't do it" that is.)